# Call to a member function addDays() on string

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to addDays to a date using Carbon with Laravel, but I don't get why I'm receiving this error. I have checked some posts in StackOverflow, but no one has helped me to solve it.

**This is my code:**

```
$user = Auth::user();
    $orders = DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $totalValue = 0;
    $percentage = 0;
    $currentDate = $carbon->now();
    $currentDate = Carbon::parse($currentDate)->format('d/m/Y');
    //$percentage = ($order->price * 0.05) / 30;


    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $nextDate = Carbon::parse($order->created_at)->format('d/m/Y');
        if(1 == 1) {
            $nextDate->addDays(1);
            DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['profit' => $order->profit]);
    }
```

**The error:**

[image: Error Laravel]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not saving your `created_at` date properly. Try following code.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$orders = DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
$totalValue = 0;
$percentage = 0;
$currentDate = $carbon->now();
$currentDate = Carbon::parse($currentDate)->format('d/m/Y');
//$percentage = ($order->price * 0.05) / 30;

foreach($orders as $order) {
    $nextDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($orders[0]->created_at)->format('d/m/Y');
    $new_date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$nextDate)->addDays(1)->toDateString();
    if(1 == 1) {
        //$nextDate->addDays(1);
        $new_next_date = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($new_date));
        DB::table('orders')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['profit' => $order->profit]);
}
```

Comment: I'm saving it as a $protected date in my model, I'm running your code. But it keeps throwing me the same error

Comment: @danhergir update with some research on issue. Please check now.

Comment: @danhergir what is you column type of  ```created_at``` in database? If it`s ```date``` then try making it ```timestamp```.

Comment: No, it’s a timestamp. That’s why this error is weird for me

Comment: @danhergir Unable to get exact and ideal solution for your problem. But I have tried to find some work around for it. I guess ```format()``` is creating problem here. Try above code, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a day before change date format like below.

```
Carbon::parse($currentDate)->addDays(1);
```

or

```
Carbon::parse($currentDate)->addDay();
```

The simple way to add a day from today date is `Carbon::now()->addDay();`

Thanks.

Comment: You probably dont even ned to `Carbon::parse` it as model timestamps (created_at/updated_at) are carbon objects by default.  You should just be able to to do `$order->created_at->addDay()` then format it afterwards.

Comment: I followed your advice, but it isn't working. It seems that I'll have to try with something else